# golang chromedp ERROR: could not unmarshal event: unknown PrivateNetworkRequestPolicy value

Tags: google-chrome, go, chromedp

I'm getting `ERROR: could not unmarshal event: unknown PrivateNetworkRequestPolicy value` while fetching amazon using chromedp. Tried with different user-agents but nothing works.

`github.com/chromedp/cdproto v0.0.0-20220816211547-b8b15824df23`    `github.com/chromedp/chromedp v0.8.4`
`Google Chrome 104.0.5112.79`

Answer (score 0):

#### What is wrong

`Google Chrome 104.0.5112.79` has such policies (see [browser_protocol.pdl#L6178-L6184](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/b5bf99e94492cd5d5fbd01786f6cfe6f4949a971/third_party/blink/public/devtools_protocol/browser_protocol.pdl#L6178-L6184)):

- Allow
- BlockFromInsecureToMorePrivate
- WarnFromInsecureToMorePrivate
- PreflightBlock
- PreflightWarn

And `github.com/chromedp/cdproto v0.0.0-20220816211547-b8b15824df23` supports the same list of polices (see [cdproto](https://github.com/chromedp/cdproto/blob/b8b15824df23c7ab5fc83bf523a80a5d2b6fae16/network/types.go#L1478-L1485)).

So the error looks impossible.

#### What to do next

The last change to `PrivateNetworkRequestPolicy` is [97.0.4665.1_9.7.3](https://github.com/chromedp/cdproto/commit/372ebae000a68baa77bd7ddf4f6472c627c50f1f) which adds two new values:

- PreflightBlock
- PreflightWarn

Please double check the version of the `chromedp/cdproto` package and the version of the browser.

Now that `Chrome 105` has been released, please upgrade to this version. Maybe it will address the issue.

It will be helpful if you can enable the debug log to record what is the invalid value. Enable the debug log like this:

```golang
ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(ctx, chromedp.WithDebugf(log.Printf))
```

Answer (score 0):

updating chromedp to the latest version fixed the issue.

Refer: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/797

```
go list -m github.com/chromedp/cdproto

github.com/chromedp/cdproto v0.0.0-20221126224343-3a0787b8dd28
```